# Can anyone identify the make of this car?

Tags: vehicle-identification

I was impressed when someone identified a Ford Prefect from a really skeletal liking!
Can anyone tell me what car is the attached?

[image: enter link description here]

This picture taken circa 1951-52 in Europe

Comment: I'm interested...but there's no image.

Comment: @David - Did that help?

Comment: @Paulster2, yes it did. I don't recognize it immediately, but will search a bit later today.

Comment: Dang, is that Anne Frank? LOL.

Comment: It looks like it could be a late 40's Nash, but definitely not sure about it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is five years late, but here goes.

After doing a reverse image search and digging into the results, this car appears to be a [Lincoln-Zephyr V-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln-Zephyr#Models) from 1939 (or thereabouts).

There is an abundance of photographs online of the Sedan and Coupe body styles for this car. However, your particular vehicle is in the Coupe-Sedan body style, and for some reason it's borderline impossible to find photographs of actual Coupe-Sedan V-12s. Fortunately, I was able to find a couple advertisements. This 1939 ad shows the Coupe-Sedan body style:

[image: Advertisement showing 1939 Lincoln-Zephyr V-12 Coupe-Sedan]

And this one shows the Convertible Coupe, Coupe-Sedan, and Town-Limousine body styles:

[image: Advertisement showing 1939 Lincoln-Zephyr V-12 body styles]

I had to resort to comparing minute details in order to confirm the identity of this car. Here are several defining features I noticed:

- The two shorter chrome trim lines above the front fender; the lower one being farther forward than the upper
- The positions of the two door hinges; one just above the longer chrome trim line, and the other a few inches above the running board
- The shape of the windows and windshield, and the angle (and material) of the split in the rear side window
- The angles and positions of the seams between the fenders and the running board
- The shapes of the fenders
- The chrome trim on the running board; it curves outward slightly where it meets the rear fender, and it ends just before the inner edge of the front fender starts to curve upward